# Is there a "Run" command for "Offer Remote Assistance"?

Tags: windows, remote-access

Is there a "Run" command for the built in windows service "Offer Remote Assitance"?

The only way I know is to open "Help and Support", and search for "Offer Remote", then click the link that comes up. But this only works on XP worksations so far as I can tell.

I know you can save it as a bookmark once you locate it the first time, but If you can't get the "Offer Remote" search result then you're dead in the water.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows XP you can use the following:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore" hcp://CN=Microsoft%20Corporation,L=Redmond,S=Washington,C=US/Remote%20Assistance/Escalation/Unsolicited/Unsolicitedrcui.htm
```

Comment: From the Run dialog you can skip the Iexplore bit: `hcp://cn=microsoft%20corporation,l=redmond,s=washington,c=us/Remote%20Assistance/Escalation/Unsolicited/unsolicitedrcui.htm` But that's a mouthful still.  Probably be nicer to create a shortcut, favorite, etc.

Comment: yeah, I was hoping for something like --> remoteas (i.e. cmd for command prompt) but it was probably a stretch...  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

On Windows 7 and Vista, it gets much easier:

```
msra /offerra <computername>
```

Comment: I'd make this the answer too if I could have more than one. Thanks!

Comment: You bet!  It's also worth noting that although Win7/Vista computers can offer remote assistance to WinXP computers, it is not possible for an XP user to offer remote assistance to a Win7/Vista machine.

Comment: and `msra.exe /offerRA` just opens the page to enter a place to connect to. You could easily save that as a shortcut on your desktop! I got this idea from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356868.aspx